# Diseño de tablas en base de datos

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Actualmente tengo una tabla llamada `Personas`, ésta tabla tiene más de 4 millones de registros.

En el sistema web que estoy haciendo hay una página de `Login` y otra página de `Registro` en caso de ser nuevo usuario. En la página de `Registro` mi idea es que la persona ingrese su **Número de Identificación** y entonces el sistema obtenga la información de ésa persona de la tabla de `Personas` y complete automáticamente algunos campos, el resto los debe completar el usuario (username, password, etc).

Ahora bien, explicando el panorama, necesito su ayuda para saber que opción es la mejor por implementar **basándose principalmente en el rendimiento de las consultas**:

1. ¿Debo crear otra tabla de `Usuarios` en la cual se registre de nuevo toda la información, incluso la de la tabla de `Personas`?.
2. ¿Sería mejor que en la tabla de `Usuarios` tenga una columna llave que haga referencia a la tabla de `Personas`, teniendo en cuenta la cantidad de registros que hay allí y que de ese total de personas, tal vez sólo se utilicen el 15%?.
3. ¿Utilizar la misma tabla de `Personas` para agregar la otra información del usuario (username, password, etc)?.

O bien, ¿qué otras opciones me recomiendan?.

Cabe resaltar que la carga de la tabla de `Personas` a la base de datos se hace desde un archivo de `Excel` con `SQL Server Integration Services` y éste proceso se puede realizar cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Si puedes crear una tabla de usuarios y la relacionas con la tabla de personas. ahora puedes crear un evento keyup que tome los valores del input y hacer una búsqueda con lo que se esta escribiendo, así te puedes traer a la persona y sus datos

Answer (score 2):

Lejos a mi parecer y como yo trabajo actualmente ese tipo de escenarios es creando una tabla **Usuarios** que contenga la `PK` correspondiente hacia la tabla **Personas**. Siendo un poco visionario y yendo más allá te serviría mucho hacerlo de esta forma para posibles reportes posteriores, tablas de **Logs** que se encarguen de guardar el historial de conexiones por ejemplo, y muchisimo más importante es que las consultas de cualquier tipo te tomarán menos tiempo, ya que tendrías menos cantidad de registros en la tabla Usuarios y sólo extraerías lo que necesitas =)

Fue una excelente pregunta Alonso!

Comment: Gracias @Paulo Urbano Rivera, pero me queda la duda que si utilizo esa forma, cuando hago alguna consulta de usuarios y personas, ¿el rendimiento de ese Select con un Inner Join no se verá afectado? , puesto que la tabla de Personas tiene más de 4 millones de registro.

Comment: Mmmmm... comentando desde mi experiencia el rendimiento no se verá mayormente afectado; obvio que si cruzas las tablas sin un `WHERE` se demorará pero aún así no tendría que ser significativo desde mi experiencia por lo menos.. veamos si surge alguna otra respuesta de alguien que haya tenido problemas, me interesó mucho la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Solo crea una tabla **USUARIO** con cardinalidad de 1 a 1 con tu tabla **TRABAJADOR**

```
TRABAJADOR (ID_TRABAJADOR, APELLIDOS, NOMBRES,..)
// ID_USUARIO ES LA PK ID_TRABAJADOR
USUARIO (ID_USUARIO, USER, PASS,..)
```

y si quieres asignar privilegios creas tabla

```
//ID_USUARIO y ID_PRIVILEGIO son PK
PROVILEGIO(ID_USUARIO,ID_PRIVILEGIO,..)
```